# Java or C# equivalent of Python freezegun or Ruby timecop

Tags: java, c#, time

I want to test highly time dependent applications written in Java or C#.

Is there a Java or C# equivalent of Python freezegun or Ruby timecop?

Comment: (I've answered rather than voting to close, as I believe the best approach is to go a different way anyway. In general, questions like this asking for library recommendations are discouraged. A better question would be "How can I test time-sensitive code in Java?" or likewise for .NET.)

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a separate library to do testing of time-based code - you just need to treat "the current time provider" as a dependency like you would anything else. So avoid calls to `new Date()`, `Calendar.getInstance()` etc in Java, and `DateTime.Now`, `DateTime.UtcNow` etc in .NET. Instead, create a `Clock` or `IClock` interface for getting "the current time" and then create a normal implementation of it which *does* use the system clock, and a fake implementation which allows you to set the time. These are pretty trivial to write, and don't need third party libraries.

Inject the clock into any code that needs it as you would any other dependency, and then you can supply a fake one in your tests with no problems.

Indeed, in Java 8 you can use the `java.time` API (which is much better than using `Date` and `Calendar`) and has a `Clock` abstract class - which includes the idea of the time zone as well. In .NET I'd probably write a simple interface and implementation based on `DateTime`, but always using a UTC kind of `DateTime`. Or use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project which comes with the `IClock` interface and a testing version.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. How can I use your suggestion to test a Java webapplication running in Tomcat of which I do not have access of the source? Could you provide an example?

Comment: @user2602898: You don't have the source for the app you're writing tests for? That's a very unusual situation... If it's been written in a hard-to-test way, there's not a lot you can do...